# How can I use multiple variables (selectors) with is() Method

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var container   = $(".container"),
    background  = $(".background");

// ...

// Inside an each() method – check if is container OR background
if (this.is(container, background)) { // Not working
    // do something
}

// I know I could do it like this ...
if (this.is(container) || this.is(background)) {
    // do something
}

// ... but I want it shorter
```

Is it even possible to check against multiple selectors as variables with is()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use this selector

```
this.is('.container, .background')
```

So basically,
**1)**

```
if (this.is('.container, .background')) {
    // do something
}
```

**2)**

```
var elements = ('.container, .background');
if (this.is(elements))  {
}
```

**3)**

```
if (this.is([container[0], background[0]])) {
    // do something
}
```

**4)**

```
if (this.is(container.add(background))) {
    // do something
}
```

**5)**

```
var temp = container.add(background);
if (this.is(temp)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Yes, I could do this but I need/want variables ;)

Comment: Another possible way to do this, yes. So it is not possible to check multiple variables inside the is() method directly?!

Comment: @Ben : Does Updated third approach solve your problem?

Comment: @Ben: I tested third approach and works for me ... it isn't something that you want?

Comment: @Ben : There are more approaches for you ... ;)

Comment: Big thanks @Parag! Was a bracketing issue on my part. Please update your last code snippet to: **if (this.is([container[0], background[0]])) { // do something }**